# Connecting Presto from Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, presto, trino

I am new to spark. I am trying to connect to presto instance using Spark Scala. For the Presto server SSL is true and I have a Presto Keystore. My question is how will I pass this information in the connection string. Below is my Code snippit

```
val enrdata = sqlcontext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:presto://hostname:1111/hive").option("query", carrier_info).option("user", "test1").option("password", "pass123").option("driver", "io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoDriver").load()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `.option("SSL","true")` option.
https://trino.io/docs/current/installation/jdbc.html#connection-parameters